# mailto Hyperlinkfied in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

i want to add hyperlinkfield which takes its value from another field.
i managed to do that but the problem is with the mailto URL,
how do i command to take another field text and mailto:  ?

```
    HyperLinkField hlf = new HyperLinkField();
    hlf.DataTextField = "Username";
    hlf.HeaderText = "Email";
    hlf.NavigateUrl = "mailto:?Subject=Disabled Alarms";
    hlf.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
    hlf.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(hlf);
    hlf.Visible = true;
```

thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hlf.NavigateUrl ="mailto:" + Textbox1.text
```